# Is there any difference in meaning between between "hold the meeting off for tomorrow" and "hold the meeting over for tomorrow"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between between *hold the meeting off for tomorrow* and *hold the meeting over for tomorrow*? For example:

> Something has come up, so let's **hold** the meeting **off** for tomorrow.
>
> Something has come up, so let's **hold** the meeting **over** for tomorrow.

Comment: In my AmE experience, hold over is usually used to mean extending or continuing, while hold off is usually meant to postpone. Some dictionaries agree and some do not.

Comment: Both of them would be improved by replacing _for_ with _until_.